# In SQLite how to control the formatting when converting a double to text

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, you can use CAST([column] as text) to convert a result in a string, however, for double this will result in having 1 decimal. How can I control whether I want to display decimals or the number of decimals displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [printf function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf):

```
> SELECT printf("%.3f", 1);
1.000
```

Comment: Do you have something that works in older version of SQLite ? The printf() function was added for SQLite version 3.8.3.

Comment: You mean outside of SQLite ?

Comment: Do you have some of "your own code" inside SQLite? ;-)

Comment: well, it is open-source, I could technically code it :) but that would be in contradiction with the fact that we have an older version deployed since in this case I could just commit all the changes to include printf() :D